# What is the best way to get the .cs file from a given .proto file with protobuf.net

Tags: json.net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

After several trial with the protobuf.net online generator, I doubt of the way y use to get the more relevant .cs file from an .proto file.

The Input proto file is the sparkplub_b file from link below:
https://github.com/Cirrus-Link/Sparkplug/blob/master/sparkplug_b/sparkplug_b.proto

In Sparkplug documentation the Datatype enums have the string form 'Uint64', and in the result .cs file we have ‘LongValue’.

(I have also to do some changes in the .cs file to be able to use enums with the 'DataType' in the JSON serialization of the object instance)

Thank you.

```
  "Timestamp": 1538568112852,
  "Metrics": [
    {
      "Name": "bdSeq",
      "Timestamp": 1538568112852,
      "Datatype": 4,
      "IsNull": false,
      "Metadata": null,
      "Properties": null,
      "LongValue": 0,
      "ValueCase": 11
    }
  ],
  "Seq": 18446744073709551615
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay, I was taking some time off. I'm the protobuf-net author.

> What is the best way to get the .cs file from a given .proto file with protobuf.net

Ultimately, for protobuf-net specifically: `protogen` - which is what https://protogen.marcgravell.com/ uses (I assume that's what you were talking about when you say "with the protobuf.net online generator")

> In Sparkplug documentation the Datatype enums have the string form 'Uint64', and in the result .cs file we have ‘LongValue’.

I assume that is coming from:

```
uint64 long_value       = 4;
```

If the concern is the *naming* (`LongValue` vs `long_value`), then note that protobuf-net has options to allow more control over this; `LongValue` is just the default convention.

However: this isn't an enum - there is no enum in `sparkplug_b.proto`. If you can be more specific about what you *want* to get as the generated code (and ideally, why), I can almost certainly help more.

(edit: there *is* an `enum` optionally generated from the `oneof`)